# How to recompile assets -- images/css/js -- in phoenix/elixir?

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

After I've called "bunch build" for the 1st time in my new project, the assets from web/static have been copied to priv/static, correct?  The next time I change some of them in web/static and call "bunch build", nothing changes. They get recompiled as I see in the terminal, but really when I run my application, there's no change. I wonder why? What should I do to recompile them completely? Should I edit them in web/static or priv/static?

Comment: Have you tried `brunch build` ?

Comment: The issue are reproduced in a sample at https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/master/docs/Phoenix%20Walkthrough.md ? If it occures, it's due to your environments(node isn't correctly installed like that).